# When running a cross validation, in my formula I come across an invalid type error

Tags: r, syntax-error, cross-validation

This is the code that my professor ran in the lab:

```
###to implement cross validation
MSE=c();cv.err=c()
for(i in 1:p){
  for(j in 1:k){
    #train the first model on all but the first fold
    train=dat[cv.ind.random!=j,]
    response=train$y
    design=train[,(2:(i+1))]; m=lm(response~as.matrix(design))
    coef=coef(m)
    ##MSE on the testing data (first fold)
    test=dat[cv.ind.random==j,]
    resp.values=test$y; 
    ##recall that the predicted values x*beta_hat
    fitted.values=as.matrix(cbind(1,test[,(2:(i+1))]))%*%coef
    MSE[j]=mean((resp.values-fitted.values)^2)}
  cv.err[i]=mean(MSE)
}
cv.err
```

[picture of cross validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24bkQ.png)

However, when I run it I get Error in model.fram.default(formula = response ~ as.matrix(design), drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
Invalid type (NULL) for variable 'response"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
[rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: p, k, and dput(dat) and dput(design) would be handy.